# asp-validation-for not working under foreach due to same name issue

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using asp-validation-for under foreach and facing following issues. suppose 3 text controls generated with foreach. I am using the [required] model annotation. "objGenExaminationTemplateChoicesModel" object is of ICollection in main model.

1. if first text controls is empty system is showing error message with
   all 3 text controls.
2. if second or third is empty system is not
   showing any message but don't proceed to post page due to model
   error.

   ```
   <table id="dtChoices" class="table table-borderless table-striped">
   <thead class="bg-primary">
       <tr>
           <th class="text-left"><label asp-for="@Model.objGenExaminationTemplateChoicesModel.FirstOrDefault().ChoiseDescription" class="control-label"></label></th>
           <th style="width:30px"><a href="#" id="AddNewChoice" class="text-warning"><span class="sidenav-icon icon icon-plus-square pull-right" style="font-size:large">&nbsp;</span></a></th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       @foreach (var objGenExaminationTemplateChoiceModel in Model.objGenExaminationTemplateChoicesModel)
       {
           iCounter = iCounter + 1;
           <tr>
               <td class="text-left form-group form-group-sm">
                   <input type="text" asp-for="@objGenExaminationTemplateChoiceModel.ChoiseDescription" class="form-control">
                   <span asp-validation-for="@objGenExaminationTemplateChoiceModel.ChoiseDescription" class="text-danger"></span>
               </td>
               <td>
                   <a href="#" class="text-warning btnDeleteRow" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteConfirmationModalAlert">
                       <span class="sidenav-icon icon icon-trash pull-right" style="font-size:large">&nbsp;</span>
                   </a>
               </td>

           </tr>
       }
   </tbody>
   ```

Comment: I also tried following line of code but does not works.                                             <input type="text" id="txtDChoiceDescription_@iCounter" name="txtDChoiceDescription_@iCounter" asp-for="@objGenExaminationTemplateChoiceModel.ChoiseDescription" class="form-control">
                                            <span asp-validation-for="txtDChoiceDescription_@iCounter" class="text-danger"></span>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `objGenExaminationTemplateChoicesModel` is a list model,so the model binding system would find the name by `[i].propertyName`.Change your code like below:

```
@model TestVmodel
<form>
    <table id="dtChoices" class="table table-borderless table-striped">
        <thead class="bg-primary">
            <tr>
                <th class="text-left"><label asp-for="@Model.objGenExaminationTemplateChoicesModel.FirstOrDefault().ChoiseDescription" class="control-label"></label></th>
                <th style="width:30px"><a href="#" id="AddNewChoice" class="text-warning"><span class="sidenav-icon icon icon-plus-square pull-right" style="font-size:large">&nbsp;</span></a></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @{ var iCounter = 0;}
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.objGenExaminationTemplateChoicesModel.Count(); i++)
            {
                iCounter = iCounter + 1;
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-left form-group form-group-sm">
                        <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.objGenExaminationTemplateChoicesModel[i].ChoiseDescription" class="form-control">
                        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.objGenExaminationTemplateChoicesModel[i].ChoiseDescription" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" class="text-warning btnDeleteRow" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteConfirmationModalAlert">
                            <span class="sidenav-icon icon icon-trash pull-right" style="font-size:large">&nbsp;</span>
                        </a>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="aa" />
</form>
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

My testing model:

```
public class TestVmodel
{
    public List<ObjGenExaminationTemplateChoicesModel> objGenExaminationTemplateChoicesModel { get; set; }
}
public class ObjGenExaminationTemplateChoicesModel
{
    [Required]
    public string ChoiseDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks good answer. Terrible naming in your example and uneeded iCounter  but worked nicely idea :)